# How to retrieve a JSON without name using Volley on Android?

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have a JSON that retrieves all the users of a database. To simplify, I will show the first two users:

```
[
    {
       "id":"1",
       "name":"Peter",
       "age":"25"
    },
    {
       "id":"2",
       "name":"Andrew",
       "age":"32"
    },
    ...
]
```

As you can see, it is an array without name that contains some `JSONObjects` so I have tried to retrieve these data from `Android` with `Volley` library going through the whole array but without success.

Here is the code that I have by the moment:

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
         try{
             if (response != null) {
                 for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                     JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                 }
             }
         }catch(Exception e){  
             e.printStackTrace();  
         }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
       Log.e("LOG", error.toString());
    }
});

queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

It always gives to me the following error:

> Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException

I also tried to retrieve the `JSONArray` before trying to retrieve the `JSONObject` but it does not allowed me because the method

```
JSONArray json = response.getJSONArray(0);
```

also gave to me the same error that I have pointed before.

I looked for a lot of examples and I cannot see where my problem is.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your server response is well-formed? I tried your JSON-oriented part of code (hardcoding the input you give as a String) and I'm not able to reproduce the error you get

Comment: @GaëtanMaisse Android Studio is giving to me that error before I could execute the code so I think the problem is about the code.

Comment: @Error404 Your code executes fine. Your app just crashes because you are parsing (or getting) the JSON incorrectly. However, as the first comment mentioned, your data must be invalid because we cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: `Unhandled exception` is a compiler error... so, let Android Studio put in the `try-catch` for your around the for loop.

Comment: @cricket_007 If I use a try-catch block around the loop I am getting the following error: `Cannot resolve constructor 'JsonArrayRequest(int, java.lang.String, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONArray>, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener)'`.

Comment: I think you put the try in the wrong place. Please update the question

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok I have edited my question.

Comment: Just curious... Did you try `StringRequest`? You can `Log.d("data", response)`, for example.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried it now and it is retrieving to me the JSON as a String.

Comment: Okay, then will `new JSONArray(response)` (as answered below) through the same error? If so, then you have malformed JSON data.

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok, now I am allowed to retrieved the information that I needed properly. Thank you very much! Your comments helped me too much, because the answer that there is below it is not too much intuitive (at least for me). One more question, why must I use StringRequest instead of JsonArrayRequest?

Comment: You don't... As I commented below you should generally only use when you are not 100% guaranteed to get a `JSONArray` (like an empty string, or HTML, for example)

Comment: @cricket_007 But I had errors on the construction of the method of JSONArrayRequest, without care about the data that was being sent. The constructor did not give to me any errors on StringRequest instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot resolve constructor '`JsonArrayRequest(int, java.lang.String, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.Listener<org.json.JSONArray>, anonymous com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener)`'

Error doesn't lie. That request doesn't accept a Method type.

```
JsonArrayRequest(
    String url, 
    Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, 
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

`StringRequest`, on the other hand, does.

```
StringRequest(
    int method, 
    String url, 
    Response.Listener<String> listener, 
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Regarding,

> Unhandled exception: org.json.JSONException

`response.getJSONObject` will throw that exception, so you must use a try-catch.

```
if (response != null) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; ...) {
            JSONObject jo = response.getJSONObject(i);
            // use 'jo'
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is more complete and intuitive. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: The JsonArrayRequest will use GET by default. You can't POST a JsonArray for whatever reason...

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 3):

You are not handling JSONException.

Give this a try.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url, 
    new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) 
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jo = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why do you try to handle your response as a String?

Comment: @Error404 That is best done for testing when your API is not guaranteed to return a JSON array. StringRequest, I mean

Comment: @cricket_007 but I am getting the error on Android Studio because it does not allow me to execute my code so I think it does not have anything related with the API in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should add final in final JsonArrayRequest
GOOD LUCK !!

final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null, new Response.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                try{
                    if (response != null) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            String tieude = obj.getString("tieudetin");
                            Toast.makeText(test.this,tieude,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            //txt.setText(tieude+"");
                        }
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.getMessage();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

```
    mQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```